# Extjs 5: Grid Search Plugin

Tags: search, plugins, grid, extjs5

I am using the search plugin for my grid in Extjs 4 and it works perfectly ,when I upgrade the application to Extjs 5 it's not work.

Is there a compatible free version of Grid Search Plugin with Extjs 5 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no free version for Ext 4 and 5 - if your plugin works in 4 it must be an unofficial version as the latest free version was for Ext 3.

You can purchase the commercial version for Ext 4 & 5 here: http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-search-plugin/

I'm the author of the plugin.